Named Entity Recognition using TFLite on Android
I have a named entity recognition TensorFlow Lite model that I trained in Python and that I would like to run on an Android. To make predictions, the model takes in a dictionary of two tensors, namely input_ids and attention_mask like so:
Inputs: {'input_ids': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
         array([[101, 2054, 102]])>, 
         'attention_mask': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
         array([[1, 1, 1,]])>}

For context, the model was trained on texts of varying lengths, so the model's default input shape for both input_ids and attention_mask is (1, 1).
Here's the code I'm using in Kotlin:
// Load model
val nerHelper = NERHelper(getApplication())
val tflite = Interpreter(nerHelper.loadModelFile())

// Set example inputShape
val inputShape = intArrayOf(1, 3)

// Create input_ids and attention_mask tensors
val inputIdsBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(inputShape, org.tensorflow.lite.DataType.FLOAT32)
val attentionMaskBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(inputShape, org.tensorflow.lite.DataType.FLOAT32)

// Example input_ids
inputIdsBuffer.loadArray(intArrayOf(101, 2054, 102))
// Example attention_mask
attentionMaskBuffer.loadArray(intArrayOf(1, 1, 1))

// Create output buffer
val outputShape = intArrayOf(1, 3, 4)
val outputBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(outputShape, org.tensorflow.lite.DataType.FLOAT32)

// Run the model
try {
    val inputs: Array<Any> = arrayOf(inputIdsBuffer.buffer, attentionMaskBuffer.buffer)
    val outputs: MutableMap<Int, Any> = mutableMapOf(0 to outputBuffer.buffer.rewind())

    // Resize inputs for input_ids and attention_mask
    tflite.resizeInput(0, intArrayOf(1, 3))
    tflite.resizeInput(1, intArrayOf(1, 3))

    try {
        tflite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputs, outputs)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("ModelInference", "Error during model run", e)
    }

    tflite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputs, outputs)
    Log.d("ModelInference", "Model run successfully")

    val output = outputBuffer.floatArray
    output.forEach { value -> Log.d("ModelInference", "Output: $value") }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.e("ModelInference", "Error during model inference", e)
}

When I run this in Kotlin, an error is thrown at
try {
        tflite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputs, outputs)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("ModelInference", "Error during model run", e)
    }

saying:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (serving_default_attention_mask:0) with 4 bytes from a Java Buffer with 3 bytes.

I understand that this error originates from there existing a discrepancy in the size between my inputs and what the model is expecting, but I'm struggling to figure out what exactly is causing this issue.
